# Use of Beanshell Preprocessor for Parameterization in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, beanshell, jmeter-plugins, parameterization

I am trying to use beanshell preprocessor for parameterization in JMeter script.My JMeter script structure is as mentioned below. Test plan->Thread group->Transaction Controller->Requests.I want to know which procedure I should follow to dynamically pass values to the request.

Description with screenshot and an example will be more helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try out the following test structure:

- Thread Group (all defaults) 1 user, 1 second ramp-up, 1 loop)

  - HTTP Request (see below for parameters)

[image: http request details]

- Beanshell Pre Processor **as a child of HTTP Request** with the following code:

  ```
  int min = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[0]); // get first parameter
  int max = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[1]); // get second parameter
  int random =  min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)); // calculate random number within parameters range
  vars.put("RANDOM_NUMBER", String.valueOf(random)); // save result into RANDOM_NUMBER variable
  ```

  and `100 300` in "Parameters: section

[image: Beanshell Pre Processor]

So in Beanshell Pre Processor we define `RANDOM_NUMBER` variable value which we refer in HTTP Request Sampler. Pre Processor is being executed **before** request so variable gets populated. If you add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you'll see that requests contain randomly generated numbers in 100-300 range

[image: SERP]

So you need to add Beanshell Pre Processor as a child of request you're going to parametrize.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting and small cookbook.

Answer (score -2):

To generate random string :

```
import java.util.Random;

chars = "1234567890abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz-";
int string_length = 36;
randomstring ="";

for (int i=0; i < string_length; i++) {
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(chars.length());
  randomstring += chars.substring(randomInt,randomInt+1);
}
print(randomstring);
vars.put("RANDOM_STRING",randomstring);
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to the question that was asked.